# in-app purchase verify receipt error

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I have created an app that uses in-app purchase. Transtactions are successfully completed while testing with my test user account but I got an error when I verify receipt in sandbox: url: https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt

```
- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];

    if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.udayKalangi.hansiMazak.hindijokes1"])
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:transaction.transactionReceipt forKey:@"proUpgradeTransactionReceipt" ];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        NSData *receiptData = [NSData dataWithData:transaction.transactionReceipt];
        NSString *recieptString = [self  base64forData:receiptData];
        NSLog(@"JSON Created");
        urlData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:[recieptString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSLog(@"will create connection");
        [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];    
    }
}
```

I got a response:

> url data: {"status":21002, "exception":"java.lang.NullPointerException"}

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you're doing this all wrong.

First, according to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html you need to set the base64 receipt data to 'receipt-data' and then post that in JSON format for verification.  It doesn't appear you are doing that.

But most of all, you're not meant to verify the receipt on the device, doing so it pointless.  You're meant to send the data to your server and have it verify the data with Apple for you.  Doing the validation on the device doesn't actually provide any validation.  The purpose of validating the receipt is to ensure it wasn't tampered with, i.e., if someone compromises your app and is able to provide a tampered receipt, they're able to circumvent the validation of that same receipt.

Comment: How does verification on the device not help? What's the difference of verifying with Apples server or your own server that verifies with Apple? It's still being done from the app.

Comment: For exactly this reason: http://www.tuaw.com/2012/07/13/russian-hacker-circumvents-ios-in-app-purchases/

In this case, the hacker has redirected the requests from Apple's servers to their own from the device.  So they can provide fake receipts as well.  But if you verify the receipt on your own server, the hacker can't redirect or alter your server's config, so you know you're (most likely) really getting Apple's servers and can trust the receipt validation.

Comment: Make sure you send a cryptographically signed Yes or No back to your app too, or the hacker can just redirect the device away from your server too.